# react native web view set source ternary

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a react native project working showing an internal HTML on a webview,

the web view renders fine if I keep the iOS or android path for the source

but when applying to the ternary comparison, the source is not set?

so this works:

```
      <WebView
    style={styles.webContainer}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={HTML_FILE}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}

  />
```

but if I do a ternary to know if is android or ios source...

```
      <WebView
    style={styles.webContainer}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={isAndroid? {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'} : {HTML_FILE}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}

  />
```

then it won't render,

so how can I check if android or ios and change the source for my web view?

Edit 1
     source={this.getSource()}

```
 getSource = ()=>{
  if(isAndroid){
   return {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'}
  }
 return {HTML_FILE}
 }
```

not working?? why?, seems I have to set source directly on webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be a syntax error. Your working code implies that `HTML_FILE` itself is sufficient as the value to pass to `source` prop:

```
<WebView
  style={styles.webContainer}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={HTML_FILE}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
/>
```

Which means that in your ternary, you shouldn't be surrounding it with `{}`. Instead, this should be fine assuming that `isAndroid` is correct:

```
<WebView
  style={styles.webContainer}
  originWhitelist={['*']}
  source={isAndroid ? {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'} : HTML_FILE}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
/>
```

**Explanation**

Let us assume that `HTML_FILE` is some variable with some value:

```
const HTML_FILE = { uri: 'some string' };
```

When the ternary as written like this:

```
isAndroid ? {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'} : {HTML_FILE}
```

attempts to resolve the else part, it will return `{HTML_FILE}` as a value. JavaScript will evaluate this using the [property value shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax) and result in returning and object that looks like the following:

```
{
  HTML_FILE: { uri: 'some string' }
}
```

Note how the name of the variable becomes a key in the resulting object and the variable's value becomes that key's value.

Removing the `{}`:

```
isAndroid ? {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'} : HTML_FILE
```

will result in the else part returning a value of `HTML_FILE` which is just the value that you originally assigned. The common confusion with React is in JSX syntax for components where you see something like this:

```
source={HTML_FILE}
```

and believe that the enclosing `{}` are necessary around all variables. This is not the case. You use them to denote an expression whose value you are assigning to the prop. See the [Specifying Attributes with JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx) where it says (emphasis mine):

> You may also use curly braces to **embed a JavaScript expression** in an attribute:

Everything inside those initial `{}` should be a normal JavaScript expression.

Answer (score 0):

make a function named getSource

```
getSource = ()=>{
 if(isAndroid){
  return {uri:'file:///android_asset/nano.html'}
 }
return {HTML_FILE}
}
```

and then set it like this

```
 source={this.getSource()}
```

Comment: hi, it is not working for ios, it will not return... return {HTML_FILE}

Comment: Can you please explain that why it will not return {HTML_FILE}. Did you check it. Can you share your code how did you implement it?

Comment: hi yes, I did called "getSource" function, but even commenting all, it still not returning correct source?

Comment: Can you share how you checked isAndroid? And also what is in {HTML_FILE}?

Comment: I am running the devices at the same time, and doing console log

Comment: No I mean how you are assigning value to isAndroid? and what is the value of {HTML_FILE}?